# Show that $ST=TS$ if and only if $ST$ is a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $S,T \leq G$. Show that $ST=TS$ if and only if $ST$ is a subgroup.

So This is excercise 2.47 of Rotman´s introduction to theory of groups. And it is just after the chapter in which he proves the three isomorphism theorems. However, I was only able to show that if $ST=TS$ then $ST \leq G$ in the following way:

Take $s_1t_1, s_2t_2 \in ST$ then

\begin{array} {lcl} (s_1t_1)(s_2t_2)^{-1} & = & s_1t_1t_2^{-1}s_2^{-1} \\ & 
= & s_1t_3s_2^{-1} \quad (T \leq G)\\ & 
= &t_4s_4s_2^{-1} \quad (ST=TS)\\  &= 
&t_4s_5 \quad (s \leq G) \\  &= 
&s_5t_6 \in ST\quad (ST=TS)\\
 \end{array}

However, in this proof, there is nothing about quotient groups nor isomorphism theorems. And Im not able to proove the other way. Is there any quotient way of doing this?

Comment: You could do $s_1t_3s_2^{-1}=s_1s_3t_4=s_4t_4$ owing to $s_2^{-1}\in S$ and $TS=ST$; this ends the proof faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I don't see how can you do quotents when we're not sure that any of the group is normal.

Nonetheless, for the other side of the proof assume that $ST \le G$ and let $x = s_1t_1 \in ST$. Obviously as $ST$ is a subgroup we have that $x^{-1} = s_2t_2 \in ST$, but also we have that $x = (x^{-1})^{-1} = (s_2t_2)^{-1} = t_2^{-1}s_2^{-1} \in TS$. Therefore we have that $ST$ is a subset of $TS$. Now similarly we have that $TS$ is a subset of $ST$, implying that $ST=TS$.

Comment: Similarly ? I disagree because we cannot use that $TS$ is a subgroup.

Comment: @ÉricGuirbal Maybe similar reasoning should have been better. At the end it's not tough to prove that $TS$ is a subgroup too, given that $ST$ is a subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

To prove the converse, suppose that $ST$ is a subgroup of $G$.
Let $s\in S$ and $t\in T$.
As $ts$ is the inverse of an element $t^{-1}s^{-1}$ belonging to the subgroup $ST$, we have $ts\in ST$, so $ST\subseteq TS$.

Now, take $x\in TS$. 
As $x^{-1}\in TS$, there exist $s\in S$ and $t\in T$ such that $x^{-1} = st$.
As a result, $x = t^{-1} s^{-1}\in TS$, so $TS\subseteq ST$.

Comment: This is a more complete answer.